# bootstrap wsyihtml5 readonly textarea

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, textarea, readonly, wysihtml5

I'm using wsyihtml5 (0.3.0) and bootstrap to make a textarea able to edit rich text.

Everything works fine except I need it readonly.

```
//Element declaration
<textarea readonly name="overview" class="form-control" id="OverviewContent"  style="width: 100%; height: 200px"></textarea>

[...]

//JS at bottom of page
<script>
    $("#OverviewContent").wysihtml5(
                                    {
                                        "font-styles":  false,
                                        "color":        false,
                                        "emphasis":     false,
                                        "textAlign":    false,
                                        "lists":        false,
                                        "blockquote":   false,
                                        "link":         false,
                                        "table":        false,
                                        "image":        false,
                                        "video":        false,
                                        "html":         false
                                    });

    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        alert("Starting disable");

        //I've tried all three of these lines individually
        $('#OverviewContent').data('wysihtml5').editor.disable()
        //$('#OverviewContent').data('wysihtml5').editor.composer.disable();
        //$('#OverviewContent').data('wysihtml5').editor.composer.element.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);


        alert("Disabled?"); 
    });
</script>
```

The textarea remains editable always it seems.

The alerts pop up fine, no console errors in chrome and the text area displays rich text fine.

Comment: what's the point of an editor if you can't use it? a simpler syntax highlighter would be a much better fit.

Comment: My objective is to display rich text. I've not much experience with this unfortunately, so I am using wysihtml5 to display it. I also use wysihtml5 to edit rich text on a separate page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $('#OverviewContent').wysihtml5();
        alert("Disabled?"); 
    });
```

just use disabled in textarea

```html
<textarea disabled name="overview" class="form-control" id="OverviewContent"  style="width: 100%; height: 200px"></textarea>
```